# How to avoid duplicates in XML while inserting into SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Note: this is a sample code and scenario. I will not be using distinct while using select statement.

I'm trying to upload Itemcodes into an empty table for the first time using XML.

below is the XML data

**`{"ProductDetails":"<Root>\r\n  <ProductDetails>\r\n    <ItemCode>2503902</ItemCode\r\n   </ProductDetails>\r\n  <ProductDetails>\r\n    <ItemCode>3591948</ItemCode>\r\n </ProductDetails>\r\n <ProductDetails>\r\n    <ItemCode>2503902</ItemCode\r\n   </ProductDetails>\r\n</Root>"}`**

When m trying to insert into the table, I'm checking if the itemcode exists in the table or not and inserting as below

```
INSERT INTO inv_productdetails(ItemCode)                                    
 select T.N.value('(ItemCode/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')          
 from @ProductDetails.nodes('Root/ProductDetails') as T(N)                                                                                                                    
 where not exists (select top 1 *  from dbo.inv_productdetails   
where                                   
ItemCode = T.N.value('(ItemCode/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') );
```

I'm not using any transaction or anything. Its a plain simple query to insert the itemcodes.

But I have noticed that while the above code runs, its not able to consider the not exists statement.

Can you please help me with a workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: I look at that and think "your DB design might be wrong"....

Comment: @MitchWheat - as i told this is just a scenario but in reality its something else..Just wanted to know how to avoid these duplicates

Comment: "as i told this is just a scenario but in reality its something else" - you want people to answer a hypothetical question, which may or may not actually represent what you are trying to do?  Good luck getting answers.

Comment: @MitchWheat - its not a hypothetical question. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behaviour.
Your `WHERE` finds no `ItemCode` 2503902 and 3591948. So the total `insert` succeeds.
Possible solutions

1.(Prefered) Make `inv_productdetails.ItemCode` unique or primary key

2.If prefered solutions is not possible for a reason, rewrite the query. You need to cleanup an input before inserting data.

```
INSERT inv_productdetails(ItemCode) 
SELECT ItemCode
FROM ( 
 select distinct T.N.value('(ItemCode/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')  ItemCode         
 from @ProductDetails.nodes('Root/ProductDetails') as T(N)                                                                                                                    
 except 
 select ItemCode 
 from inv_productdetails) t;
```

Comment: Primary key and distinct not possible. I have given a sample XML with one column. I have around 20 columns in the XML. If a product is created and deleted we need to maintain it in the database with IsDeleted=1. So cant put a primary key on ItemCode. In the 20 columns there are ItemCode,barcode,fmdcode which are unique respectively not combined. So wanted to know a work around.

Comment: As I said, the second solution is to cleanup your input before inserting. For the case you've posted `except` will do.

Comment: Will give it a try. Thank you